# Use of echo and system to run a software in C

Tags: c, shell, blast

I am trying to run a biological program called BLASTP which takes in two strings (fasta_GWIDD and fasta_UNIPROT in the code) and compares them. The problem that I am encountering is the use of echo/system in the code. Can anyone suggest what am I missing out??

```
    for(i=0;i<index1;i++)
    {
        sprintf(fasta_GWIDD,">%s\\n%s\n",fasta_name1[i],fasta_seq1[i]);
        setenv("GwiddVar", fasta_GWIDD, 1) ;
        sprintf(fasta_UNIPROT,">%s\\n%s\n",fasta_name2[i],fasta_seq2[i]);
        setenv("UniprotVar", fasta_UNIPROT, 1) ;
        system("blastp -query <(echo -e $GwiddVar) -subject<(echo -e $UniprotVar)");
    }
```

The error is:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `blastp -query <(echo -e $GwiddVar) -subject<(echo -e $UniprotVar)'
```

Comment: First make syntax of the argument for `system` acceptable by your shell.

Comment: Lets suppose $GwiddVar=">P10747_1\nMLRLLLALNLFPSIQVTGN" and $UniprotVar=">P10747_2\nMLRLLLALNLFPSIQVTGN".
The following command works perfectly fine when run from terminal/command line:
blastp -query <(echo -e ">P10747_1\nMLRLLLALNLFPSIQVTGN") -subject <(echo -e ">P10747_2\nMLRLLLALNLFPSIQVTGN");

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the shell does not understand the

```
<(echo -e $GwiddVar)
```

syntax. Mind that the `system` command may use different shell than the one you are used to (like csh instead of bash, and so on). It's everything in somewhere in your OS config files and profile, but I can't guess what you have out there.

Btw. I think that you should be able to check which shell is being used by the `system()` command by either of these:

```
system("echo $SHELL")  // should simply write the path to current shell
system("ps -aux")      // look at it and find what is the parent of the PS
```

etc.

Considering that this was correct on some shell:

```
blastp -query <(echo -e $GwiddVar) -subject<(echo -e $UniprotVar)
```

The syntax cited above apparently is meant only to pass the variable as intput. I think you are overdoing it. You are using `echo -e $GwiddVar` to print and capture the data, which you already have in a vairable at hand. Have you tried something as simple as:

```
blastp -query $GwiddVar -subject $UniprotVar
```

I don't know which shell you are trying to use, but considering that `echo` got its data, then it should be exactly the same.

If you are worried about spaces, then various shells usually allow you to use quotation marks:

```
blastp -query "$GwiddVar" -subject "$UniprotVar"
```

**Of course it depends on the shell.** If your program uses a shell that does not like quotation marks, well, you have to adapt it. Not to your shell, but to the shell the `system()` has used.

Another thing is that using `system` is quite rough. When you have arguments that are difficult to escape correctly, you should be using other functions [like execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) that are able to take an array of real raw direct strings and pass them directly as ARGV to the process. Using these, you will not need (and you should not) add any quotes or escape any spaces in the strings to be passed.

```
sprintf(fasta_GWIDD,">%s\\n%s\n",fasta_name1[i],fasta_seq1[i]);
sprintf(fasta_UNIPROT,">%s\\n%s\n",fasta_name2[i],fasta_seq2[i]);

char** args = .....; // allocate an array of char*[5], malloc, or whatever
args[0] = "blastp";
args[1] = "-query";
args[2] = fasta_GWIDD;
args[3] = "-subject";
args[4] = fasta_UNIPROT;

int errcode = execve(4, args, null);
if( errcode ) ... // check the error (if any) and react
```

However! Note that the execve comes from the exec family, so it replaces your current process. This is why I write only a sketch and don't show the whole ready-to-run code. You will probably need to `fork()` before it and then wait for the children in the outer loop.

So, I'd first check the shell and syntax ;)

Comment: My shell is $echo $SHELL:/bin/bash and I tried the following without any success:

system("blastp -query $GwiddVar -subject $UniprotVar);
Error:Command line argument error: Argument "subject". File is not accessible: 

system("blastp -query \"$GwiddVar\" -subject \"$UniprotVar\"")
Error:Command line argument error: Argument "subject". File is not accessible:

Comment: `Argument "subject". File is not accessible` sounds like the blastp treats the received data it as a file name. Still, it seems that both of the lines without `echo`s worked and blastp was at least started. According to **[this page about BLAST+](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK1763/)** both `-query` and `-subject` are expecting a FILENAME, not a direct string. Have you tried this way? Write the contents of each of the variables to some separate temporary file and than pass `-query file1 -subject file2`?

Comment: Yeah I have already tried using filename and have been successful as well. But the problem is that I have to work with 10000 or more entries and opening/closing a file takes too much time. So wanted to replace the filename just with the string as mentioned for Python program in the link: https://www.biostars.org/p/88563/

Comment: Hooo.. so that's what you're afteer. Search for "redirect standard input" or "redirect stdin" and "pipe". For example, [here's how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716359/redirect-child-processs-stdin-and-stdout-to-pipes). It's not the best text you can find, but a good start. In general, that's a whole another story and not a short one, I can't guide you now, sorry. You can also ask here specifically about stdin/stdout redirection. It's quite a common question, lots of resources and ready answers.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 3 system`:

```
DESCRIPTION
    system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
    command, and returns after the command has been completed.
```

On many systems, `/bin/sh` is not `bash`, and even when it is, it is a different configuration of `bash` (`bash` typically operates differently if it is invoked as `/bin/sh`). So, you are passing `bash` syntax to a shell that is either not `bash`, or doesn't allow the full set of `bash`-isms... Also, there's a space missing after `-system` that might be confusing things as well... And, I'm not entirely sure environment variables are expanded within `system()` strings...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. But how to circumvent the problem because my shell is indeed /bin/bash.

Comment: I'm not sure what else your code does, but this looks like an example of attempting to write a shell script in C. Why not just write a shell script? Something like `for f in <some list of files>; do GwiddVar=<something>; UniprotVar=<something>; blastp -query .... ; done`...