# C program to test other programs with repeatable input and no restart

Tags: c, linux, performance, process, sudoku

I'm trying to write a C program that is able to test the performance of other programs by passing in input and testing the output without having to restart the program every time it runs. Co-workers and I are writing sudoku solvers, and I'm writing the program to test how fast each one runs by solving numerous puzzles, which could all be in different languages, and I don't want to penalize people for using languages, like Java, that are really slow to start up. Ideally, this program will start the sudoku solver program, keep it running, and continually pass in a new puzzle via `stdin` and test the output in `stdout`.

Here's pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
start a sudoku solver in another process
once process is running
    pass puzzle string into child stdin
    wait until output comes into stdout
    repeat until end time limit ends
close process
```

I've messed around with [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), but I couldn't figure out how to write to the child process `stdin`. I've done a bunch of poking around the internet, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I'm running this on a Linux box. It doesn't have to be `stdin` and `stdout` for communication, but that would be the easiest for everyone else.

Comment: You need to spend a few weeks reading more about Unix programming, e.g. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or some newer book. You basically want to understand how a shell works. Most [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) or batch processors are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so study their source code. But your question is too broad.

Comment: You also need to define common conventions and protocols. Look also into `batch` command.

Comment: Study [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).  In particular [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and more.. Read also more about OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Note that the Sudoku solvers will have to be written so that they loop, solving problems while there is more input.  If they're written to solve one problem, there's nothing you can sanely do to make the solve a second problem except by restarting them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The idea would be that you'd pass in a new line with a sudoku puzzle into stdin after getting a response.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal: so you are defining a bit of protocol. Good. But document your protocols and conventions entirely. You could want some more structured protocol (e.g. perhaps using [JSON](http://json.org/), separated by newlines)

Comment: You should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716359/redirect-child-processs-stdin-and-stdout-to-pipes) and use [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) family of functions after the `fork`.

Comment: I think you my just want `popen ()`

Comment: @technosaurus with [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) you only get a unidirectional pipe.

Comment: If you want to "cheat" and use the TCP/IP network stack instead, which may be easier than POSIX-specific IPC, you can pipe their programs to/from `netcat`.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This is more a long comment than an answer, but your question is really too broad and ill-defined, and I'm just giving some hints.</sup>

You first need to understand how to start, manage, and communicate with child processes. **An entire Unix programming book is needed** to explain that. You could read [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or some newer book. You need to be able to write a [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)-like program. Become familiar with many [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) including  [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and a dozen others. See also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

You also need to **discuss with your colleagues some *conventions* and *protocol* about these sudoku programs** and how your controlling program would communicate with them (and the evil is in the details). For example, your pseudo-code is mentioning "pass puzzle string" but you don't define what that exactly means (what if the string contains newlines, or weird characters?). Read also about [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

<sup>(You might want to have more than one sudoku process running. You probably don't want a buggy sudoku client to break your controlling program. This is unclear in your question)</sup>

You could want to define a [text-based protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) (they are simpler to debug and use than [binary protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_protocol)). Details matter a lot, so document it precisely (probably using some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation). You might want to use textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org), [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). You could take inspiration from [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) etc (or perhaps choose to use one of them).

Remember that [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s and [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)-s [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s are just a *stream of bytes* without any message boundaries. Any message organization above these should be a *documented* convention (and it might happen that the message would be fragmented, so you need careful buffering). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

<sup>(I recommend making some free software sample implementation of your protocol)</sup>

Look also into similar work, perhaps [SAT competition](http://www.satcompetition.org/) (or chess contests programs, I don't know the details).

Read also something about OSes, like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Great answer. I will say, though, I didn't need a whole Unix programming book to do this (with my Hearts AI I was testing). Some Googling around about named pipes got me what I needed, but I already knew about message boundaries and had used TCP sockets before.

Comment: No, that won't be enough. You need at least to know half of [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) and that is much too long to fit in an answer. In particular, you need to understand why [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) is needed, and that takes several chapters of explanation. My last paragraph about pipes being just a stream of bytes is important. OP probably don't realize the "message boundary" thing

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `poll` might not be really required if parent and the child agree on a input/output convention while passing size information carefully.

Comment: It depends what the OP really wants. His question is too broad and we can only make guesses

Comment: If OP wants to handle the case of a buggy sudoku client (e.g. which loops indefinitely in outputting garbage or in waiting for input) he probably needs `poll`